Data-table Filters not working in shadcn-ui/radix-ui dialog component
I'm using the data-table from shadcn-ui when I render it inside a dialog the filters don't work.
I'm using radix-ui with shadcn-ui.
I looked in the inspect tab the dialog component is rendered below all the script tags in the body element.
Console tab
I'm not sure if this is the reason it's not working as it should be.
Here's the link for a dev environment replicating the issue
Dev Environment

there's no code, you only show html inspect, what can we do to help you ?

@cantdocpp Hi thanks for the comment. I've created a stack blitz environment for you to have a look at the problem. Open The details tab and then try to filter in any column.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nwvycw

Hi, i posted my answer below, let me know if there's something wrong so I can check it again

I see your code and fiddle with it.
From what I could see, your problems stems from tour DebounceInput components.
First of all, it doesn't return the correct value when the value change, and there's problem with it's render, I found out that it can trigger continuous re-render.
In order to solve it, you can change your DebounceInput component to be like this:
export default function DebounceInput({
  value: initialValue,
  onChange,
  debounce = 500,
  ...props
}: Props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      onChange(value);
    }, debounce);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  // You used to listen to onChange event, I don't know why
  // But I speculate that's the cause of multiple re-rendering
  }, [debounce, value]);

  return (
    <Input
      {...props}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}

And inside your DataTable component, you can create a input change handler function and pass it to the DebounceInput component like this:
function handleGlobalFilterChange(val: string) {
    setGlobalFilter(val.toString());
}

And pass it to your DebounceInput component like this:
<DebounceInput
      debounce={200}
      value={globalFilter}
      onChange={handleGlobalFilterChange}
      className="max-w-sm p-2 mb-2"
      placeholder="Search all columns..."
/>

Also don't forget to infer the new correct type in your DebounceInput component props like this:
type Props = {
  value: string;
  // This change
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
  debounce?: number;
} & Omit<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, 'onChange'>;


Thanks, man, that was really helpful.
I added the onChange in the useEffect dependency array because eslint was showing me react-hooks/exhaustive-deps error. I never thought that was the issue because the table was still functioning well normally.
Your answer was a huge help.
Thank you very much.

thank you too for creating the sandbox environment! i couldn't have solved it without it. Your code is more complex than I've thought. It'd be almost impossible to solve by reading the question here
